# Android Food Fight Winners!

Tags: discussion

**Ice Cream Sandwich was the clear winner**, with over 5 times the page views as Gingerbread!

As for individual winners...

**In the Ice Cream Sandwich tag:**

- The prize for the most viewed question goes to eldarerathis, for asking [What actually happens when you swipe an app out of the recent apps list?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/what-actually-happens-when-you-swipe-an-app-out-of-the-recent-apps-list). This question was viewed 802 times during the Food Fight!
- eldarerathis's question also had the highest score (20!). However, each user is only eligible for one prize, so the prize for the question with the next highest score goes to John for asking: [How can I send a file wirelessly without bluetooth or a Wi-Fi network in ICS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19985).
- The prize for the answer with the highest score goes to Austin Mills, for answering: [What actually happens when you swipe an app out of the recent apps list?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19995). His answer finished the contest with a score of 11.

**In the Gingerbread tag:**

- The prize for the most viewed question goes to Matthew Read, for asking: [What do I need to know about the “weird” Galaxy S Vibrant emergency call handling?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19996) His question got 160 views during the contest.
- The prize for the question with the highest score goes to michelemarcon, for asking: [What's the meaning of signal strength colors in battery usage screens?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20053). This question ended the contest with a score of 4. (Matthew Read's question above also had a score of 4, but each user is only eligible for one prize.)
- The prize for the answer with the highest score goes to GAThrawn, for answering: [What's the meaning of signal strength colors in battery usage screens?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20065) This answer had a score of 4 at the end of the contest.

Congratulations to our winners, and thanks to everyone who participated! Winners will be contacted shortly to arrange prize purchases.

Comment: Awesome, thanks SE!  But wow, I feel bad with only 160 views.  Glad the ICS questions did better ;)

Comment: Congrats to all!

Comment: Wow, congrats all. I too feel a little undeserving with just the four votes needed in Gingerbread, extra congrats to the double and triple figure scores and views in ICS!